# how to load data from db to crystal report in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable, combobox, crystal-reports

```
 viewdata.Visible = True
    Dim a As String = fromdtp.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim b As String = Todtp.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim type As String = sel.SelectedItem.ToString()
    If sel.SelectedItem.ToString = "allitems" Then

        Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From entry where delivery between '" & a & "' and '" & b & "' "
        MessageBox(searchQuery)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(table)
        viewdata.DataSource = table

    Else
        Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From entry where p_name='" & type & "' and delivery between '" & a & "' and '" & b & "' "
        MessageBox(searchQuery)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(table)
        viewdata.DataSource = table
    End If


    Form3.Show()

        fromdtp.Value = Date.Now
        Todtp.Value = Date.Now
```

this is my form code after clicking the button i want to generate a report depend on the query 
And i want to load data from Sqlserver to Crystal Report in VB.net

Comment: Visual Studio has good debugging tools so you don't have to use MessageBox and then forget to take it out later.

Comment: If you use Parameters in your SQL strings you will not only avoid disasters (Mr. & Mrs. Table's little boy Drop) but you won't have to worry about quotes and dates and such.

Comment: thank you Mary for your Response